# Sending a number from python to app using android studio

Tags: python, android-studio

I am currently working on a capstone project. One of the things that I am trying to achieve is to be able to get a number sent from a python code and get it displayed on my app that I am building through android studio.

My general knowledge on how to tackle this would be to set my python as a client which sends the number and android studio as a server which displays the number however I am having trouble on how to proceed with this and would appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest solution would be for you to create a very basic [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) server (not client!) on a Python host, and have it handle a basic GET call, which will be invoked from the Android client, using an implementation of your choice, see [this](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) tutorial for example